# Обработка SOAP-запроса

Tags: php, xml, soap

Есть `Soap-запрос`:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://207.105.137.104/S.asmx?wsdl");

$api = $client->GetPartQty(array('UserID'=>$UserID,'Password'=>$Password,'PartNumber'=>$PartNumber));
print_r ($api);
```

Получаю такой ответ :

> stdClass Object ( [GetPartQtyResult] => stdClass Object ( [any] =>
>   SINGLERANRS999297RS9000XL SERIES SHOCK76.4600ActiveCOMPTON,
>   CA12COPPELL, TX0JACKSONVILLE, FL9DENVER, CO14COLUMBIANA, OH4POST
>   FALLS, ID6 ) )

В консоли появляется `xml`-ответ.

Вопрос 1: Как получить результат из каждого тега `xml`? 
Вопрос 2: `UserID и Password` постоянны. `PartNumber` должен меняться. Как его правильно задать, чтобы я получал ответ по каждому `PartNumber`?
Зы: в переменной PartNumber находятся абсолютно не связанные между собой значения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить результат можно вот таким образом: `$api->GetPartQtyResult`.

Т.е., по сути, надо писать не `print_r($api);`, а `print_r($api->GetPartQtyResult);`

А чтобы `$PartNumber` был всегда разный, можно это делать в цикле.

Например `$PartNumber` меняется от 0 до 100, то получится

```
$parts = 100;
for ($PartNumber = 0; $PartNumber < $parts; ++$PartNumber) {
    $client = new SoapClient("http://207.105.137.104/S.asmx?wsdl");

    $api = $client->GetPartQty(array('UserID'=>$UserID,'Password'=>$Password,'PartNumber'=>$PartNumber));

    print_r ($api);
}
```

Если чисел много, то лучше использовать генераторы: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.generators.syntax.php

http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1999

**UPD.**
Если `PartNumber` не просто числа от 1 до 100 , а набор артиклей. Что-то в виде "rs45655" " rs656777", то можно для чисел сделать смещение `offset` а `rs` конкатинировать при запросе:

```
$start = 456555;
$end = 656777;
$count = $end - $start;

for ($i= 0; $i < $count ; ++$i) {
    $PartNumber = 'rs'.($start + $i);

    $client = new SoapClient("http://207.105.137.104/S.asmx?wsdl");

    $api = $client->GetPartQty(array('UserID'=>$UserID,'Password'=>$Password,'PartNumber'=>$PartNumber));

    print_r ($api);
}
```

Comment: А если PartNumber не просто числа от 1 до 100 , а набор артиклей. Что-то в виде "rs45655" " rs656777"? То есть никак не связаны. И результат хотело с

Comment: @Denis ну ведь никто не мешает вместо `'PartNumber'=>$PartNumber` написать `'PartNumber'=> "rs".$PartNumber`  и цикл задать от 0 но со смещением $offset

Comment: @Denis обновил ответ. попробовал описать как будет

Comment: Опять таки ЧИСЛА НЕ СВЯЗАНЫ это не порядок чисел от и до,  это могли бы быть даже просто буквы или имена. В этом и гвоздь ((

Comment: @Denis ну так надо и формулировать вопрос корректно и более полно, со всем необходимым описанием, чтоб не появлялись новые обстоятельства по мере уже написанного ответа... .Потому, что название переменной `PartNumber` указывает на число, а никак не на содержание букв....Напишите подробно в вопросе дополнительные сведения

Comment: По сути все так и осталось только в PartNumber( Manufacturer Part Number в интернет магазине) все они никак между собой не связаны. В этой переменной могли бы быть имена ( Вася Коля Оля), или другие не связанные значения.Вот что я имел в виду. Прошу прошение за недопонимание((

Comment: @Denis ну список этих `Part Number` вы можете где-то взять? Вы же откуда-то берете те значения, которые в запросе фигурируют. Собственно как и `UserID` с паролем. Из базы данных, так? Выбираете из БД массив этих юзеров, а потом в цикле `foreach` делаете тоже самое.